# Make sin the same width as cos

Tags: spacing, align

I am trying to typeset a two-line formula, where the top and the bottom are almost identical. The differences are the signs (plus to minus) and the trig-functions (`\sin` to `\cos`). I want most of the terms in the formulas to align nicely.

[image: not well aligned formula]

For the minus, I used `\hphantom{-}`, but I also need to increase the width of `\sin` so that it is as wide as `\cos`. How can I do that?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
x(t) &= \hphantom{-} r_+ \sin(\omega_+ + \phi_+) + r_- \sin(\omega_- +  \phi_-)  \\
y(t) &=             -r_+ \cos(\omega_+ + \phi_+) - r_- \cos(\omega_- + \phi_-) 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**: I originally asked about making the plus sign have the same width as the minus sign. Thanks for pointing out that they already have the same width, and sorry for the red herring.

Comment: I would rather use more `&` and the `alignat*` environment or use a `typewriter` like font with equal character box widths

Comment: + and - have the same width; it's sin and cos that have different width.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that “sin” and “cos” have different widths.

For this special occasion you can define a variant of `\Sin` that has the same width as `\cos`; the excess space is put to the left of “sin” that, at least in this case, seems not noticeable, because the eye sees the alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Sin}{%
  \mathop{\sbox0{$\cos$}\makebox[\wd0][r]{$\sin$}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
x(t) &= \hphantom{-}r_+ \Sin(\omega_+ + \phi_+) + r_- \Sin(\omega_- + \phi_-)  \\
y(t) &=            -r_+ \cos(\omega_+ + \phi_+) - r_- \cos(\omega_- + \phi_-)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't think the spacing between `\Sin` and the left bracket is a little off?

Comment: @1010011010 No, it's just optical due to the relative shapes. Look at it at high resolution.

Answer (score 5):

This proposition does not change the size of `-` or `+` characters, but rather use the `&` and the `alignat*` environment. I think this would be possible, but **sin** and **cos** do not have the same width as well, which is the cause of this non-alignment.

I added some markup commands for quicker typing of the `\sin` and `\cos` functions.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\sinspecial}[1]{r_{#1} \sin(\omega_{#1} + \phi_{#1})}
\newcommand{\cosspecial}[1]{r_{#1} \cos(\omega_{#1} + \phi_{#1})}


Original version
\begin{align*}
x(t) &= \hphantom{-} r_+ \sin(\omega_+ + \phi_+) + r_- \sin(\omega_- +  \phi_-)  \\
y(t) &=             -r_+ \cos(\omega_+ + \phi_+) - r_- \cos(\omega_- + \phi_-) 
\end{align*}
With some more \& - characters \\
\begin{alignat*}{4}
x(t) &= \hphantom{-} r_{+} \sin(\omega_{+} + \phi_{+}) &\,+\, &r_{-} \sin(\omega_{-} +  \phi_{-})  \\
y(t) &=             -r_{+} \cos(\omega_{+} + \phi_{+}) &\,-\, &r_{-} \cos(\omega_{-} + \phi_{-})   \\
\\ 
x(t) &= \hphantom{-} \sinspecial{+} &\, + \, &\sinspecial{-} \\
y(t) &=             -\cosspecial{+} &\, - \,&\cosspecial{-} \\
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Especially the last version looks great. I did not know about `alignat` before - I will take a deeper look at it!

Comment: I may be annoying, but why did you add the useless `\mleft` and `\mright`?

Comment: @egreg: Yes, annoying as usual ;-) I thought `\mleft` etc. would provide better spacing here, but it's the same as just using `(`... etc. I will change later on

Comment: the spacing of the "inner" plus and minus in the middle pair is incorrect..  if you want to get the correct spacing, always either put the `&` immediately before a `+r` element, or place `{}` on either side of the plus or minus to show that it's a binary operator.